# Interface Implementation error : cannot find symbol

Tags: java, interface

I am implementing the following sample interface:

```
package test1;
    public interface MotorVehicle {
        void run();    
        int getFuel();
    }
```

In the class

```
package test1;
import test1.MotorVehicle;
public class Car implements MotorVehicle
{
    int fuel;

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Running");
    }
    public int getFuel(){
        return this.fuel;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the class file , I get the following error :

```
Car.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public class Car implements MotorVehicle
                            ^
  symbol: class MotorVehicle
1 error
```

Compile Steps:

**Step:1** `javac MotorVehicle.java`
**Step:2** `javac Car.java`

Both my interface and the class are in the same directory , why does ut come up with cannot find symbol error?

Edit:
As suggested , have changed the package , and tried to run the same code again . Still getting an error.

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to compile it? Are the classes in any package (do they have a `package` declaration)?

Comment: Have you add your directory to the classpath? Which IDE o you use?

Comment: @Dibya it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Did you `import` the interface? Did you declare them to be in the same package? If you've done neither I fail to see why that should compile.

Comment: @dibya - He will still get that error .

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes they are in the same package

Comment: Show us how you compile them.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Mate updated the question with `package` details and `import`. Still getting the error.

Comment: Maybe problem in language. Try re-enter code. Because use your example and all fine. Use Eclipse IDE

Comment: Are both classes inside the folder "test"? That's what the `package` information says. If this information is inconsistent with the actual situation, you might get errors.

Comment: @blueygh2 `MotorVehicle.class` is inside `Test` , `Car.class` isn't created as there is a compilation error

Comment: @misguided I meant the `.java` files.

Comment: Yes , both are under the same folder

Comment: @misguided The folder name has to match the package name. That's what I meant. (In general, the folder structure mirrors the package structure)

Comment: @misguided as has been suggested below, if both classes are inside the same folder/package, you don't need to import them. They will be visible to each other (unless declared otherwise by modificators)

Comment: This console shows that you are inside the test1 folder but as you have a package statement it will search in the folder where you currenty are. it will work fine if you create a folder named test1 and put the interface inside it

Comment: Set the classpath and it will compile just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're in the wrong folder when compiling.
From the console screenshot, it is clear that you are inside `/test1`. However, the `package test1;` statement expects a folder inside the current folder named `test1`. It can't find that folder/package, so you get an error.

The solution is to go up one folder, so you end up in `/src`, then compile using the path to the file, e.g. `javac test1/Car.java`. Explanation: You are in the folder `/src`, the `package` statement inside the classes says they are inside the folder `test1` which is inside `/src`. Now every package/path can be resolved.

And you shouldn't `import` things that are in the same package.

Comment: Thanks for explaining . Clears up the whole thing now. COmplining fine now , after implementing your suggestion. I liked the simple language in which you have explained , hence accepted the answer

Answer (score 2):

First of all as your package name is  `test` you must keep your class and the interface in a folder named `test`.

Second thing since they are in the same folder named `test` remove `import test.MotorVehicle;` from the class defination

Suppose if your folder `test` resides in `g:/` such that g:/test/contains class and the interface.

Then try opening the command prompt in `g:/`

then type the following commands

for compiling

```
javac test/Car.java
```

and for executing

```
 java test.Car
```

Though you may get `Error: Main method not found in class test.Car`
 as your class does not contain main mathod

Comment: He is not trying to Run and Car doesn't have a main method

Answer (score 1):

You are going in to exact path by the use of `cd` command.Because of that interface is not accessible as class will try to find out it from package from current/running location.

For make this compile you have to specify fully *(again Fully)* qualified name of package during compilation.

**For Example**

If you class is in `a.b.test` **package** compile it like this

```
javac a/b/test/Car.java
```

Answer (score 0):

First compile `MotorVehicle` as it doesn't have any dependencies. Then set the classpath

Before issuing `javac Car.java` compile statements you need to set the `Classpath`

Windows

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;<PATH_TO_COMPILED_BINARY>/
```

Unix

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:<PATH_TO_COMPILED_BINARY>/
```

`<PATH_TO_COMPILED_BINARY>` should not include the package `test1`

Example :

C:/sourcecode/test1

Then `<PATH_TO_COMPILED_BINARY>` should be C:/sourcecode

**Update**

Removing the `import test1.MotorVehicle` will also fix the issue.

Comment: javac is working fine , as I am able to compile other java files successfully .Is setting classpath still required?

Comment: Yes, you need to set the classpath to point to the package test before compiling car.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not talking about source code but compiled .class files. Sorry for the misunderstanding, please look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

After Compiling ***Motorvehicle.java***. you have to ***create a folder test1*** and transfer the ***MotorVehicle.class*** into the folder test1 then compile the next file Car.java. This will solve your error